# How can I stop redis graceful when mem and swap is full?

Tags: redis

Last night, I run a job to insert data into a redis set(because I want keep my data unique).
After I wake up this morning, I find insert operation because very slowly.
Htop shows Memory usage  `1884/2015MB` and  swap usage  `1019/1021MB`
 
I realize that 2G memory can not hold redis. 
Then I run `shutdown` in `redis-cli`, but no action, waiting and waiting...
I also try `service redis_6379 stop`, but terminal stop at `stoping...`.

What can I do to make redis save all data to dump.rdb and close it graceful?

Answer (score 1):

Normally, a simple `redis-cli shutdown` should suffice.

Are you using periodical snapshots? If yes, you might be safe to reboot your machine. One important thing to note is that enabling periodical snapshots doubles the memory usage since Redis has to create an in-memory copy of the dataset before writing it to disk.

Another important thing is to follow the advices from [Redis setup hints](http://redis.io/topics/admin), if you haven't already.

This might not answer your question, but should help you avoid it from happening again.

Comment: I was wondering why redis took such big memory just now. Thanks for you explaination , now I understand.But if I turn off periodical snapshots and redis eat up all memory what should I do?`redis-cli shutdown` seems be waiting redis-server reply,redis-server seems be busy with something, just not work.

Comment: That's a question I currently don't know how to answer. Do redis-server answer to any other commands normally? If not, it might have panic'd due to the memory pressure. Not sure if that makes sense, maybe [@antirez](http://stackoverflow.com/users/130155/antirez) could help?